# How to make comparison using JSON/jQuery and PHP data

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms, comparison

I am currently using a JQuery code and a JSON file to load cities in a select> according to the chosen state/province. The JQuery is below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('../../../js/statesCities.json', function(data) {
        var items = [];
        var options = '<option value="">Selecione</option>';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            options += '<option value="' + val.sigla + '">' + val.sigla + '</option>';
        });
        $("#estados").html(options);

        $("#estados").change(function() {

            var options_cidades = '<option value="">Selecione</option>';
            var str = "";

            $("#estados option:selected").each(function() {
                str += $(this).text();
            });

            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                if (val.sigla == str) {
                    $.each(val.cidades, function(key_city, val_city) {
                        options_cidades += '<option value="' + val_city + '">' + val_city + '</option>';
                    });
                }
            });
            $("#cidades").html(options_cidades);

        }).change();

    });

});});
```

The JSON code I am using: https://gist.github.com/letanure/3012978

And the HTML selects:

```
<div>
    <b>Estado:</b>
    <select id="estados" class="form-control" name="estadoCliente" required>
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <b>Cidade:</b>
    <select id="cidades" class="form-control" name="cidadeCliente" required>
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In fact, this code works just fine. But when I want to fill a form using PHP data, the code doesn't help. (The registration page is the same as editing. On the edition page, PHP loads user's information). If all the states and cities were pre-loaded in the HTML (Have all options typed), in order to check which state and city are in the database, I would use an inline PHP's ***if***, considering the variable $state as the state of any user who filled in this form.

> `<option <?php echo $state=='AB'?'selected': ''?>>AB</option>`

But It can't be used because the function *$.each* won't accept the variables from PHP. So, my question is how can I do this verification to each option, having the state and city saved in a database? I will use this code to load the data of a user, so I can edit information more easily.

*PS: I don't know how I could better describe this question on the title.*

Comment: What is the question exactly. As far as I understand your post, you are able to generate your selects using javascript and now you would like to do the same thing using PHP if the user is already registered and make their city and province pre-selected? Have you tried some things or don't you even know where to start?

Comment: Somehow I get the feeling you don't know php is a server language. You just don't in line a php statement and expect php will respond to a JavaScript change event.

Comment: @Lou I have this registration page, where the admin is able to register users. But I programmed it in a way that the editing page is the same as the registration. So, when editing a user, the system must load the data from the database, and make the comparison. Gotcha?

Comment: @Xorifelse Of course I know that. The PHP is not part of the algorytm that load cities. Actually, that inline code is used on editing page, to check what is the state and the city of a user, and put a 'checked' attr on the corresponding option. Did you understand?

Comment: @GuilhermyCamargo and what is the database technology that you use?

Comment: @Lou I use mySQL with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @GuilhermyCamargo There are a few approaches to do what you want. You could build your selects only using PHP by parsing your JSON file in the backend and comparing with your results from your query or you could pass the result to your frontend and do your conditioning from there. Personnally I'd do it in PHP but if you want to keep your javascript for some reason, you can output your query result using json_encode in a script tag or fetch the data using an ajax request (This last one is pretty bad but it would work). What do you think?

Comment: @GuilhermyCamargo You can just pass your user's cities and states using json_encode from your mysql query result. something like `echo "<script>var userdata = " . json_encode($data)  .";</script>";` and then add the conditionning to the javascript you already have using your userdata object.

Comment: @Lou I am using JavaScript because jquery is asynchronous when it updates the cities option. I think only PHP is not able to solve both problems I have (Load cities as the state are selected; Put a 'selected' attribute on corresponding cities and states of a user, whose data is loaded in PHP).

Comment: @Lou, I forgot to tell that I still am a beginner when we talk about PHP/JavaScript integration. I think I have understood your answer, but could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're loading the data on the frontend you will need to store the backend values somewhere, then once the data has loaded, use the JS to compare and select the correct option.

In your html you could do (supposing you're not using a templating engine):

```
<div>
    <b>Estado:</b>
    <select id="estados" class="form-control" name="estadoCliente" initial-val="<?php $estado; ?>" required>
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <b>Cidade:</b>
    <select id="cidades" class="form-control" name="cidadeCliente" initial-val="<?php $cidade; ?>" required>
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Above you should see the use of `initial-val="..."`, you can call this whatever you want. You will use these values when the data loads...

So, your JS would now use those, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('../../../js/statesCities.json', function(data) {
        var items = [];
        var options = '<option value="">Selecione</option>';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            options += '<option value="' + val.sigla + '">' + val.sigla + '</option>';
        });

        // always cache your jquery dom lookups in a var if queries more than once.
        var $estados = $("#estados");
        var $cidades = $("#cidades");

        $estados.html(options);
        $estados.change(function() {

            var options_cidades = '<option value="">Selecione</option>';
            var str = "";

            $("option:selected", $estados).each(function() {
                str += $(this).text();
            });

            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                if (val.sigla == str) {
                    $.each(val.cidades, function(key_city, val_city) {
                        options_cidades += '<option value="' + val_city + '">' + val_city + '</option>';
                    });
                }
            });
            $cidades.html(options_cidades);
            $cidades.val($cidades.attr("initial-val"));

        }).change();

        // now set the value on the "estados" <select> and trigger the change event, so the above code runs to change "cidades"
        $estados.val($estados.attr("initial-val")).trigger( "change" );

    });

});});
```

That, I hope gets you a solution you can build upon.

Comment: Dude, really thank you for the answer. But I think your code adaptation is only focused on loading the cities of the selected state. What I need is to check what is the state and city of a specific client (whose data, is loaded on PHP), who has already filled the form. Am I right, or did not I understand what you did?

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your question then. I'm not sure I do even now. This code change allows your form to essentially restore the values the user had previously selected and likely saved to your database in a previous session/page load.

Comment: My problem is the registration page is the same as the editing page. So, when it is loaded to edit user's information, the code must check what state and the city were selected.

Comment: @GuilhermyCamargo but has the information been saved? If so, then my suggested answer would solve the problem you are facing. It will reselect the options the user selected. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. The data is saved in a MySQL database. Yeah, I tried your solution. When I am at the editing page the selects get like (https://image.ibb.co/jCWhTy/aaa.png).

Comment: OK, and are you setting `$estado` and `$cidade` to the value that is saved in the database? If you're doing that, are there any javascript errors showing in your console Also. if you inspect the html source, can you see the `initial-val="..."` attributes with the values you expect?

Comment: I just discovered something, when I select a state which does not correspond to the user's state, the cities **select** is blank, but when I select the real user's state, the cities **select** automatically chooses the right city. This is really a big advance.

Comment: YEAH DUDE! You are right all the time. The variable which contains the state had another name. That is why it was not working.

Comment: Great stuff! So if you fix the value, does it reselect the value correctly for the state?

Comment: For some reason I tought the user could have more than 1 city and province. Just pointing out that initial-val is not a valid input attribute. Just for the sake of making it valid you could use a data attribute such as data-initial-val and then use $cidades.data('initial-val'); to access it.

Comment: I am not sure if I got what you are asking. On editing page, when I change the state, the cities *select* gets blank, like in the picture. And If I choose the right state again, the saved city is automatically rechosen (I just loved that). The only remaining problem is the select gets blank, but you have already answered my initial question.

Comment: You said initial-val is not a valid input attribute. I don't know why, but the form submission had no problem. I changed states and cities and submitted a few times, and it works perfectly.

Comment: This won't break the code, well maybe in some very picky browsers. It's just not conventional. Also everytime the $estados element will change this code will try to select the initial-val attribute from $cidades. The automatic selection of the city should be done only once, when the document has loaded.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I will try to figure something out in order to solve this. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Yes, this isn't a complete solution. This is just "showing you the way"  as it were, i.e. demoing how to use a backend variable in a delayed manner on the frontend after loading dependent resources. What you could do is apply it only once by either removing the initial-val attr, or setting another to say it's been initialised correctly (I do use this technique myself). You need to solve the problem of the blank dropdowns though for it to work correctly. Investigate the value of the initial-val, use some console.logs to work out why the state isn't preselected correctly.